# get image from bytes blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I am developing a blackberry application which retrieves image from the server , some of images are being retreived and other give error in the encodedImage Line

```java
            ImageFromUrl _img = new ImageFromUrl(item.getThumbLink());
            byte[] bytes = _img.getbitmap();
            Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(width, fieldHeight);
            if (bytes != null) {
                // bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmapFromBytes(bytes, 0,
                // bytes.length, Bitmap.SCALE_TO_FIT);
                EncodedImage image = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(bytes,
                        0, bytes.length);
            }
```

and that's the connection which get the bytes

```java
ImageFromUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public byte[] getbitmap() {

    try {

        connection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(
                url + Connection.getBlackBerryConnectionParams(),
                Connector.READ, true);

        InputStream is = connection.openInputStream();

        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bStrm = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        int ch;
        while ((ch = dis.read()) != -1) {
            // System.out.println((char) ch);
            // msg = msg + (char) ch;
            bStrm.write(ch);
        }
        dataArray = bStrm.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return dataArray;
}
```

how can I solve that to get all images without errors ?

Comment: What "error" are you getting?  Is this code throwing an exception?  If so, what Exception is being thrown?  Also, it looks like your variable `dataArray` is a member variable ... it's not declared in the `getBitmap()` method.  That doesn't look right.  You should either make that variable local to the `getBitmap()` method if you don't need it elsewhere, or make sure to `null` it out each time you call `getBitmap()`.  The way it is now, your code can catch an Exception, and then return the `dataArray` value from the last time `getBitmap()` was called, which is probably wrong.

Comment: the error is in the runtime it gives Illegalargument exception

Comment: that can happen if the byte[] has bad data.  like i said, your dataArray variable looks like it could return bad data, based on what code is shown.   can you put a breakpoint on the e.printStackTrace() line?  your code is just continuing to return dataArray even if there's an IOException.  you might be missing the first exception thrown (before the IllegalArgumentException)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromUrl(String url)
{
Bitmap bitmap=null;
try
{
    HttpConnection connection=(HttpConnection)Connector.open(url);
    connection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
    InputStream is=connection.openInputStream();
    int length=is.available();
    byte[] data=new byte[length];               
    data=IOUtilities.streamToBytes(is); 
    connection.close();
    is.close();
    bitmap=Bitmap.createBitmapFromBytes(data,0,data.length,1);
    if(bitmap!=null)
        return bitmap;
    else
        return bitmap=Bitmap.getBitmapResource("noimage.png");

}
catch (Exception e) 
{
    return bitmap=Bitmap.getBitmapResource("noimage.png");
}
}
```